# How to filter within a pivot_longer

Tags: r, pivot, tidyverse, tidyr

I am working with a dataset where I need a pivot a series of columns however I should filter out all the records that are all NULL within each group.
Below is an example

```
    library(tidyverse)

courses_col = c("Science",     "Mathematic",    "French",         "Biology")

mapping <- tibble(
    courses  = courses_col,
    level =  c("aaaa", "aaaa", "bbbb", "cccc")
)

score <- tibble(
    name = c("Bob", "Simon", "Albert", "Marc"),
    French = c("A", "A", "B", "C"),
    Science = c("A", "B", NA, "C"),
    Mathematic = c("A", "A", NA, NA),
    Biology = c("A", "B", NA, "B"),
    score = c(12, 14, 15, 12)
)


score %>%
    select(name, Science, Mathematic, score) %>%
    filter(!is.na(Science) & !is.na(Mathematic)) %>%
    summarise(ratio = median(score))

score %>%
    pivot_longer(
        cols = courses_col,
        names_to = "courses",
        values_to = "grade"
    ) %>%
    left_join(mapping, by = "courses") %>%
    filter(!is.na(grade)) %>%
    summarise(
        ratio = median(score)
    )
```

For the first code, I am getting a median value of 13 for the group "aaaa" corresponding to the courses "Science" and "Mathematics" - notice that I am manually filtering the NA value if both columns are NA.

However, when I pivot the data I am losing the possibility to apply a filter for the group. The second example produces a median of 12 because it drops all NA.

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: It is nog clear to me what your desired output should look like.. can you provide it?

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this after you pivot you need to use `group_by` and `filter`:

```
score %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = courses_col,
    names_to = "courses",
    values_to = "grade"
  ) %>%
  left_join(mapping, by = "courses") %>%
  dplyr::group_by(name) %>%
  dplyr::filter(sum(is.na(grade) & courses %in% c("Science", "Mathematic")) < 2) %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup() 

  name  score courses    grade level
   <chr> <dbl> <chr>      <chr> <chr>
 1 Bob      12 Science    A     aaaa 
 2 Bob      12 Mathematic A     aaaa 
 3 Bob      12 French     A     bbbb 
 4 Bob      12 Biology    A     cccc 
 5 Simon    14 Science    B     aaaa 
 6 Simon    14 Mathematic A     aaaa 
 7 Simon    14 French     A     bbbb 
 8 Simon    14 Biology    B     cccc 
 9 Marc     12 Science    C     aaaa 
10 Marc     12 Mathematic NA    aaaa 
11 Marc     12 French     C     bbbb 
12 Marc     12 Biology    B     cccc
```

Comment: Thanks, however, this drop all NA, what I really need is a filter applied for cases where all the grouping columns are NA

Comment: In your example, which grouping columns are all `NA`? Your first output is a 1x1 tibble with a value of `14`, I don't see any grouping variables and `NA` only exists for one `name` in `Science` and `Mathematic`.

Comment: What is your grouping variable? And do you want to drop the entire row when there is `NA` for all `French`, `Science`, `Mathematic`, and `Biology`?

Comment: The group is defined in the `mapping` dataframe. For example, in the groupping "aaaa", If I see a `NA` in both Science and Mathematic then this entire row must be dropped.  In the example you can see that the row for Albert is filtered out but not the one from Marc. Hope it makes sense

Comment: The grouping "aaaa" is only Science, not Mathematic and Science.

Comment: in the mapping tibble you can see "aaaa" defined for "Science" and "Mathematic" - this is what drive the groups

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228478/discussion-between-lmc-and-michael).

Answer (score 0):

We can use `values_drop_na`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
score %>%
  pivot_longer(
     cols = courses_col,
     names_to = "courses",
     values_to = "grade", values_drop_na = TRUE
 ) %>%
  left_join(mapping) %>% 
  summarise(ratio = median(score))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, however, similarly to the previous answer, this drop every NA, in this instance I only want to drop the NA that are present for all columns of each group (notice the filter & AND in the first example)

Comment: @Michael IN your example, there is no case like that

Comment: maybe refresh the page, I updated the example with this detail

Answer (score 0):

@Michael.

When you pivot_longer the dataset, you increased the number of values of **score column**. Remembering **Median** is the middle value of dataset.

So, in your first example:

```
score %>%
select(name, Science, Mathematic, score) %>%
filter(!is.na(Science) & !is.na(Mathematic)) %>%
summarise(ratio = median(score))
```

The **output** will be:

| name | French | Science | Mathematic | Biology | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | A | A | A | A | 12 |
| Simon | A | B | A | B | 14 |

In this example to we calculate the median we have to:

(12 + 14) / 2 = 13 --> The result you found.

But, in the second example:

```
score %>%
pivot_longer(
    cols = courses_col,
    names_to = "courses",
    values_to = "grade"
) %>%
left_join(mapping, by = "courses") %>%
filter(!is.na(grade)) %>%
summarise(
    ratio = median(score)
)
```

The **output** is:

| name | score | courses | grade | level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 12 | Science | A | aaaa |
| Bob | 12 | Mathematic | A | aaaa |
| Bob | 12 | French | A | bbbb |
| Bob | 12 | Biology | A | cccc |
| Simon | 14 | Science | B | aaaa |
| Simon | 14 | Mathematic | A | aaaa |
| Simon | 14 | French | A | bbbb |
| Simon | 14 | Biology | B | cccc |
| Albert | 15 | French | B | cccc |
| Marc | 12 | Science | C | aaaa |
| Marc | 12 | French | C | bbbb |
| Marc | 12 | Biology | B | cccc |

In this Example, you increased the number of observation to column **score**. To calculate the **Median** to this case, we have to **order** the values, take the two numbers in the middle, sum and divide by 2, like we did before.

So, we have:

| Number | Number of Cases |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 7 |
| 14 | 4 |
| 15 | 1 |
| Total: | 12 |

Let's order the numbers to know which them are in the middle of dataset:

12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15

Well, ordering the numbers we see the two numbers in middle are:

12, 12, 12, 12, 12, **12, 12**, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15

Thus, lets calculate the median fir this second example:

(12 + 12) / 12 = 12 --> A different median.

To solve this problem I back the dataset to the original shape, adding some new columns:

```
score %>%  pivot_longer(
cols = courses_col,
names_to = "courses",
values_to = "grade") %>%
left_join(mapping, by = "courses") %>%
pivot_wider(names_from = courses, values_from = c(grade, level)) %>%
summarise(ratio = median(score))
```

To rename the columns I used:

```
col.names <- c('name','score','Science', 'Mathematic','French','Biology', 'level_1','level_2','level_3','level_4')
colnames(score) <- col.names
```

Hope this was helpful.

Follow a link to if you want to know more about Median: [purplemath.com/modules/meanmode.htm](https://www.purplemath.com/modules/meanmode.htm)